# Mockito - InvalidUse Of MatchersException

Tags: java, exception, mockito

I'm trying to mock up some classes, but the following code gives me problems:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CalendarServiceTest {

    private Calendar calendar;

    @Mock
    MyClient myClient;

    @InjectMocks
    CalendarService calendarService;

    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        List<Proposal> proposals = new ArrayList<>();
        calendar = org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Calendar.class);
        Proposal proposal = new Proposal();
        proposal.setAmount((float) 109.5);
        proposals.add(proposal);
        calendar.getProposal().addAll(proposals);
        when(calendar.getProposal()).thenReturn(proposals);
    }

    @Test
    public void getCalendar(){
        initMocks();
        when(myClient.getCalendar(anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), new LocalDate(), new LocalDate(), new LocalDate(), new LocalDate(), anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(calendar); // <<== exception here
        Assert.assertNotNull(calendar);
    }
}
```

Running this get's me:

```
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the error says, if you use matchers then all of the arguments need to use them, e.g.:

```
eq(new LocalDate())
```

Or if you don't care about the value of the `LocalDate`s use:

```
any(LocalDate.class)
```